# Drawing on Form in C# using CreateGraphics()

Tags: c#, drawing, system.drawing

I'm trying to get drawing on C# Form working, but after reading documentation about Graphics class and Draw/Fill methods It still doesn't work for me.

It's the code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Drawing_Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Constructors

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3f);
            Graphics surface = CreateGraphics();
            surface.DrawEllipse(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));

            pen.Dispose();
            surface.Dispose();
        }

        #endregion Constructors
    }
}
```

When I press Start an empty form appears, no drawings. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do the drawing in the constructor because the `OnPaint()` method will overwrite it all when it's called by the framework later.

Instead, [override the `OnPaint()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce(v=vs.110).aspx) and do your drawing there.

Do NOT create your own `Graphics` object using `CreateGraphics()`; instead, use the one passed to `OnPaint()` via `e.Graphics` as per the example I linked.

(Also, don't dispose `e.Graphics` when you're done with it - the framework manages that for you.)

Comment: Works great! Thanks for help ;)