# How do you access a Graphic inside a Timer in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, graphics, timer

I need to access a Graphic inside a Timer method, I just don't know how to... Does anybody know how to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        string[] Blocks = { "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW", "WHITE" };
        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RedChosen()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Red is chosen");
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int Location = rnd.Next(1540);
            Graphics RedEnemy = this.CreateGraphics();
            Pen selPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
            RedEnemy.DrawRectangle(selPen, Location, 0, 64, 64);
            RedEnemy.Dispose();
        }

        private void SummonTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int Block = rnd.Next(5);
            switch(Blocks[Block])
            {
                case "RED": RedChosen(); break;
                case "BLUE": BlueChosen(); break;
                case "GREEN": GreenChosen(); break;
                case "YELLOW": YellowChosen(); break;
                case "WHITE": WhiteChosen(); break;
            }
        }

        private void EnemyMoveTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to access `RedEnemy` as EnemyRed in `EnemyMoveTick`. For `BLUE`, `GREEN`, `YELLOW` and `WHITE` the same code applies as `RedChosen`, except for the colors, which have changed corresponding to their name.

Comment: Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. -

Comment: Please note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.  The system needs to draw all the controls' surfaces at times you can't control; therefore all you want to add to those surfaces must be created from the one event that the system will call, which is the `Paint` event.

Comment: Have you tried to use the same code as you use in the constructor?

Comment: In your Timer.Tick you should Invalidate the control where the graphics shall be painted. In the Paint event you need to know all data like colors, positions, states etc needed to draw the __whole__ scene!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `this.CreateGraphics();` [is not the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594357/drawing-on-form-in-c-sharp-using-creategraphics). You should instead override the `OnPaint` method (or attach an event handler to the paint event.)

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var graphics = e.Graphics;
        // Do your drawing
        //...
    }
```

And call `this.Invalidate();` to trigger a paint event. You should separate the game state from the drawing, so you can run all the game logic, either from a timer or when the user interacted in some way, and call Invalidate to trigger the redraw.

If you have some special need, like only wanting to draw heavy objects when needed, or less frequently than the window, it is possible to draw to a bitmap:

```
    private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
        {
            // Do your drawing
            //...
        }
    }
```

And use `graphicsToPaintWith.DrawImageUnscaled(myBitmap, new Point(0,0))` in your OnPaint method to draw the bitmap to the window. You will need to ensure the bitmap is the correct size etc for this to work correctly.